# How to access resources that are newly added while running? JAVA SPRING BOOT

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, resources

I got a spring boot application. Where I serve images from my front end. However, when I serve one it gets saved in the target directory?.

My springboot structure is the standard and I got my images in the src/main/resources/images folder. And I try to read them in using
`File fileFolder = new File(new ClassPathResource("/images/").getURI());`

However this gives me back the target/images that is build when I run my project. However, I want it to be dynamic so when a image is newly added in I want my app to read them in and give them to my front end. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

When you build the project, Maven copies the content from src/main/resources to target/classes, hence the images would not have the new images. You should probably use an external directory for such purposes when you want to load the new images that you'll keep on adding on the server.